# Why is the O(n^2) solution faster? Day 1 Advent of Code 2020

Tags: go, big-o

I have two solutions for the first Problem from Advent of Code. The first solution (`p1`) has the time complexity of O(n). The second (`p2`) of O(n^2). But why is the second faster?

https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/1

BenchmarkP1   ​    12684         92239 ns/op
BenchmarkP2         3161         90705 ns/op

```
//O(n)
func p1(value int) (int, int){

    m := make(map[int]int)

    f, err := os.Open("nums.txt")
    printError(err)
    defer f.Close()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        intVar, err := strconv.Atoi(scanner.Text())
        printError(err)
        m[intVar]=intVar
    }

    for _, key := range m {
        l, ok := m[value-key]
        if ok {
            return l, key
        }
    }
    return 0, 0
}

//O(n^2)
func p2(value int) (int, int){

    var data []int

    f, err := os.Open("nums.txt")
    printError(err)
    defer f.Close()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        intVar, err := strconv.Atoi(scanner.Text())
        printError(err)
        data= append(data, intVar)
    }

    for ki, i := range data {
        for kj, j := range data {
            if ki != kj && i+j == value {
                return i , j
            }
        }
    }
    return 0, 0
}
```

Comment: What does n correspond to in the code?

Comment: How big is the input? For small inputs, O(n2) may be faster than O(n). Big-O notation only described the asymptotic complexity (i.e. when n is large).

Comment: @mkrieger1 to the searching loops. For both functions the last loop

Comment: @jub0bs I have tested it with 200 values and 400

Comment: @jub0bs Ah at 800 it swaps. I thought 200 values was enough, but apparently not. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Just **try more test data**:

```
func main() {
    // generate txt
    generateTxt(10000)
    // test
    time := countTime(p1)
    fmt.Println("time cost of O(n^2): ", time)
    time = countTime(p2)
    fmt.Println("time cost of O(n): ", time)
}

func countTime(f func(int) (int, int)) int64 {
    tick := time.Now().UnixNano()
    fmt.Println(tick)
    f(2020)
    tock := time.Now().UnixNano()
    return tock - tick
}
```

### result(ns):

| data | O(n) | O(n^2) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | 510700 | 529900 |
| 5000 | 787900 | 4589600 |

### explanation

**Big-O** means how the time cost increase while data scale increase, so small size data cannot reflect this well.

And also notice: p1 need to make a map with some time cost. if you try p2 after p1, the io of p2 might be benifited from cache too.